# JSON visualisation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, json

I've got database with json stored as an attribute. Is there any way to parse this information and visualize in QGIS? Here is the basic concept.
Example: I would like to display label from JSON.val2 on polyline.

[image]

Comment: Does every JSON datum contain the same name/attribute pairs? Or is it more ragged than that? Are you interested in any particular attributes? What kind of database is it? Could you extract the JSON and turn it into a id/key/value table in your database and then make a relational link to the spatial data?

Comment: It's PostGIS layer. I cannot do any things connected with beckend side. I can't use substring() because of different lenght of values.

Comment: QGIS can do regex parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750127/regex-for-parsing-single-key-values-out-of-json-in-javascript But you can't always parse JSON with regex.